# Is there a way to get all Internet Message Headers of an item attachment?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a requirement to read all Internet Message Headers of an Item Attachment.
Using following query, it is possible to get headers. But not all.

```
var itemAttachment = await graphServiceClient.Users["id"]
                .Messages[messageId]
                .Attachments[messageWithItemAttachment[0].Id]
                .Request()
                .Expand($"microsoft.graph.itemAttachment/item")
                .GetAsync();
```

I have found following resource which provides a way to read missing headers of an item.
[Get message using Graph missing some InternetMessageHeaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60947499/get-message-using-graph-missing-some-internetmessageheaders)

I need to know how can I use such expansion within a expand query?